# Form refresh issue windows form ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to refresh a form after every 30 minutes if the datagrid is empty. My code is as below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindDataGrid();

    if (dataGrid_FileList.RowCount <=0)
    {
        Timer refreshTimer = new Timer();
        refreshTimer.Interval = 30000;  //30 seconds in milliseconds
        refreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshTimer_Tick);
        refreshTimer.Start();
    }
}

void refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.InitializeComponent();
    BindDataGrid();

    if (dataGrid_FileList.RowCount>0)
    {
        InhouseDownloadeer_Shown(this, null);
    }
}
```

This code works well when RowCount of datagrid is `<=0` but it's continuing even after the datagrid contains rows `> 0`. How can I prevent refreshTimer_Tick if the datagrid contains rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also stop a Timer. Declare the timer variable outside the method.

```
Timer refreshTimer = new Timer();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    refreshTimer.Interval = 30000;
    refreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshTimer_Tick);
}
```

Now simply call `refreshTimer.Stop();` when needed in another method.

PS `asp.net` and `winforms` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You call the if statement just after the databind methode. And I think it executes before your datagrid binds its rows.

For me you should remove this code from your refreshTimerTick event :

```
    if (dataGrid_FileList.RowCount>0)
    {
       InhouseDownloadeer_Shown(this, null);
    }
```

Like :

```
    void refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        BindDataGrid();        
     }
```

And put it in the DataBount event

```
  void dataGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (dataGrid_FileList.RowCount>0)
        {
            InhouseDownloadeer_Shown(this, null);
        }    
  }
```